# Is a 8-Bit IPS display necessary for web designing?

Tags: website-design, color, image-quality, monitor

I'm doing web design (not print or photography) and I'm wondering if I should spend extra money on a display that provides more accurate colors.

I'm already set on buying IPS since they're easier on the eyes, but I don't know if i should just settle for 6-bit or be more concerned about color accuracy and go with 8-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I honestly wouldn't worry about colour accuracy for web. Every person in the planet will see the site in a different shade (so to say). One thing is using web safe colours, that will actually make a difference if you have, for example, overlapping layers (like a non-transparent image on the same colour background). But a website will be seen in anything from an old 15" to a monster 30"+ monitor, passing though mobile, and everything with different resolutions, brightness, contrast, etc. I'd go for a comfortable decent sized monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll just go with the cheaper IPS panel then :)